# Google app script prompt to rename tab when duplicated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple script that duplicates the current tab in a sheet and moves it to the left but what I'd like to also add is a line that will also prompt me to name/rename the new duplicated tab.
Currently I have this

```
function TemplateDuplication()

    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet();
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().moveActiveSheet(1);
    }
```

so basically when the script runs it duplicates the tab, moves it to the left, and asks to be renamed. Is that doable?

Comment: Did you have a look to the dialogs documentation? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Yes, it's doable. If you need further help, please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: yes but I am not a developer by any means. I googling as much as I can to try and make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) and [PromptReponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response) classes you can show a dialog box requesting an input.

This modification will show a dialog box requesting a name and leaves the default value if non is entered:

```
function TemplateDuplication(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var newName = ui.prompt("Enter a new name for the new Sheet- Optional").getResponseText();
  var newTab = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().moveActiveSheet(1);
  if(newName) newTab.setName(newName);

}
```

This version shows the dialog box until a new name is entered:

```
function TemplateDuplication(){
  do{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var newName = ui.prompt("Enter a new name for the new Sheet- Required").getResponseText();}
  while(!newName);  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet().setName(newName);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().moveActiveSheet(1);

}
```